# Laravel 4 & Sentry 2 extending the sentry class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, inversion-of-control, cartalyst-sentry

Having some issues trying to extend the sentry class in Sentry 2. Here is what I have done and what I am trying to do:

Created a new facade:

```
namespace pusers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class ADSentryFacade extends Facade {

    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'pusers\adsentry';
    }

}
```

Extedned the sentry class(all the use namespaces are there just removed to clean it up in the post). There will obviously be a lot more to this just trying to get it working at this point:

```
namespace pusers;

class ADSentry extends \Cartalyst\Sentry\Sentry {   
    public function authenticate(array $credentials, $remember = false, $adUser = false)
    {       
        return (string)$this->throttleProvider->isEnabled();
    }
}
```

Inside of app.php I changed the alias from:

```
'Sentry' => 'Cartalyst\Sentry\Facades\Laravel\Sentry'
```

to

```
'Sentry' => 'pusers\ADSentryFacade'
```

The Problem:
When I use my alias its almost like nothing except the actual Sentry class is starting up. So as you can see I am trying to see if throttling is enabled or not. Using my alias(always return true) it doesnt use the config.php file but if I change it back to use the normal alias it works just fine(returning false as I have it set to false in the config).

Any hints on what I am doing wrong? I couldn't find anyone trying to extend the actual Sentry class. The only thing I found was on the sentry 2 forums one of the admins recommended someone to create a new facade and then extend Sentry but that's it.

Any other information I can provide just let me know whats needed.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well figured it out, got just enough pointers in the cartalyst channel!

I went ahead and created a service provider. Changed the app name from sentry to adsentry. Then in my facade I changed it from 'pusers\adsentry' to just 'adsentry' and that did the trick!